# Return exception error message into a variable Laravel

Tags: laravel, exception

i'm doing a single function to login with Firebase in laravel, it works correctly but i'm trying to capture the error message into a session variable then redirect to the login view but instead it shows the laravel error view. How could i avoid this?. Thanks!

[image]

```
public function login(Request $data) {
        $email = $data->input('email');
        $password = $data->input('password');

        try {
            $user = $this->auth->verifyPassword($email, $password);
            Session::put('user_uid', $user->uid);
            Session::put('user_email', $user->email);
            return redirect('/');
        } catch (Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\InvalidPassword $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            Session::put('message', $message);
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's throwing `InvalidArgumentException`, but you are only catching the `Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\InvalidPassword` exception.

Comment: What is the PHP version you are using ?

Comment: i'd tried catching InvalidArgumentException too, but even when i try with an invalid password i get the same error page. Im using php 7.1.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch `Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException` as

```
public function login(Request $data) {
    $email = $data->input('email');
    $password = $data->input('password');

    try {
        $user = $this->auth->verifyPassword($email, $password);
        Session::put('user_uid', $user->uid);
        Session::put('user_email', $user->email);
        return redirect('/');
    } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\InvalidPassword $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        Session::put('message', $message);
        return redirect('login');
    } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        Session::put('message', $message);
        return redirect('login');
    } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Auth\SignIn\FailedToSignIn $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        Session::put('message', $message);
        return redirect('login');
    }   
}
```

If you are using PHP 7.1+

```
public function login(Request $data) {
    $email = $data->input('email');
    $password = $data->input('password');

    try {
        $user = $this->auth->verifyPassword($email, $password);
        Session::put('user_uid', $user->uid);
        Session::put('user_email', $user->email);
        return redirect('/');
    } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\InvalidPassword | \Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException | \Kreait\Firebase\Auth\SignIn\FailedToSignIn $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        Session::put('message', $message);
        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```